# mongorestore error: assertion: 4 Missing expected field "currentVersion"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dump, mongorestore

In the process of moving my server, I encountered this error when using mongorestore:

```
assertion: 4 Missing expected field "currentVersion"
```

What does it mean? What should I do to restore from the dump directory?

The command I used was:

```
mongorestore dump
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the new server uses an outdated MongoDB -- version 2.6.

When installing it, I just retrieved it from the default repository.

I had some problems installing an up-to-date version as my server was 32-bit, forcing me to migrate to a 64-bit machine.

Comment: How did you restore? what was the solution?

Comment: I just migrated to a more expensive 64-bit machine at Scaleway.